# How should I install TeX-Live 2010 on top of the existing installation?

Tags: 10.10, package-management, latex

I found the install-tl script, but it installs texlive into `/usr/local`. Can I trick it into installing it **on top** the current texlive 2009 installation?

PS. Does anyone think it si worth the trouble?

Comment: Having TL 2010 installed is worth the trouble. Not sure why you want one on top of the other, however. See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) for basic tips on just having TL 2010 installed. If you want both, as far as I know, you don't need to do anything special, you just to make sure the one you want to use comes first in your $PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know how to do that using update-alternatives?
If you do please post the steps.
Thanks.

I did another approach

1. Edit the /etc/enviroment file as root and add the path directly,
   like:
   `sudo gedit /etc/enviroment`
2. then add the path, it should look something like this (if you distribution is 32 bit)

   PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/i386-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
3. logout or reboot
4. next puge kile out of you system
   `sudo apt-get purge kile kbibtex` then
5. add this PPA   https://launchpad.net/~koshi/+archive/ppa
6. update and reinstall kile

P.S. Just one note, when you do a `sudo tlmgr update --all` it wont work. You just have to do a `sudo su` then  `tlmgr update --all`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have both at the same time, you could install Tex-Live 2010 to `/usr/local` and then use `update-alternatives` to point to the executables you would like to use.